# How to track employee expenses in SuiteCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Is there a way to track employee expenses in SuiteCRM? The default installation does not have anything related to expenses and I could not find any documentation nor any paid module to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not such a module in the base installation, but depending on your requirements you could create your own using the module builder.

You could create such a module with a relationship to users, defining a few fields like

- amount
- user (related field)
- type of expense
- date of expense
- project (related field) [optional]

You could even add a file upload for attaching the picture.

If you really need the employees to have access to this, you could create a small app that communicates with the API so its a lot easier to just track expenses.